# I speak but I don't speak and I move but don't move. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I speak but don't speak and I move but don't move. What am I?

Comment: This looks too broad in its current state. You might try adding more to it.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing this could turn out to be quite broad, here's my take.

Is it -

> A Speech

I speak but don't speak

> A speech speaks to people through a speaker but being a non living thing, can't speak itself.

I move but don't move

> It can move people emotionally but again, it can't move itself.